# Larvel - how to return view with token

Tags: laravel, routes, parameters, laravel-8

```
Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', [PasswordResetController::class, 'showResetPasswordPage'])->name('password.reset.token');
```

```
   public function showResetPasswordPage(Request $request)
    {

        $token = $request->route()->parameter('token');

        return view('resetpassword')->with(
            ['token' => $token]
        );
    }
```

I have this as my route in web.php - if it pass the parameter as 1234 as the token reference, the view is returned and I can grab the token.

However, the API I'm using sends a reset code like this 'PKKGhoTq6Po3HzgpqThGyN1g8%2F%2BvPabz' which if I pass to the url - comes up as not found.

Is there a way to parse this so I can return the view with the token as it works when using 1234?

Any help would be appreciated.

Tried different parameters / route setups with no avail.

Comment: Remove `$token = $request->route()->parameter('token');` and replace the function signing with this `public function showResetPasswordPage(Request $request, string $token)` and it will be available

Comment: Thanks! I've tried as you've suggested and it works again with '1234' but not with 'PKKGhoTq6Po3HzgpqThGyN1g8%2F%2BvPabz' - wondering if Laravel is rejecting it because of the character format?

Comment: Seems that was the case - I added ->where('token', '.*'); to the end of the route in web.php and now the view is loading and token available.

Comment: Be sure you answer your own question to close the question and get credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that was the case - I added ->where('token', '.*'); to the end of the route in web.php and now the view is loading and token available.

In web.php this is the route which was returning the view:

```
Route::get('/password/reset/{resetCode}', [PasswordResetController::class, 'showResetPasswordPage'])->name('password.reset.resetCode')->where('resetCode', '.*');
```

Controller:

```
    public function showResetPasswordPage(Request $request, string $resetCode)
{
    return view('resetpassword')->with(
        ['token' => $resetCode]
    );
}
```

Adding ->where('resetCode', '.*'); to the end of the route stopped Larvel from filtering the token and passed it to the view without issue.

Comment: Please share the final code, so that you help your fellow users.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).